# Using ng-click and ng-blur at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement [this](http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/32/creating-an-angularjs-autocomplete-tag-input-widget)

It is AutoComplete Tag Input Widget, [image]

This is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="com.htmlxprs.autocomplete">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Angular Autocomplete Tag Input</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="TagController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 top-buffer">
            <div auto-complete url="/search" model="data.tags"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the autocomplete-template.html template used within directive:

```
<div class="tags-wrapper">
<div id="tagsList" class="tags-cloud">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Start typing" 
                id="searchInput" 
                ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" 
                class="form-control" 
                ng-model="searchText" 
                ng-change="search()"/>

    <div ng-repeat="selectedTag in selectedTags" class="tag">
        <span class="tagName">{{selectedTag}}</span>
        <span>&nbsp;<b ng-click="removeTag($index)" class="fa fa-times cross"></b></span>
    </div>

</div>
<ul id="suggestions" class="suggestions-list">
   <li ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions" 
            class="blockSpan" 
            ng-click="addToSelectedTags($index)" 
            ng-mouseover="$parent.selectedIndex=$index" 
            ng-class="{active : selectedIndex===$index}">{{suggestion}}
    </li>
 </ul>
```

and this is the js code:

```
angular.module('com.htmlxprs.autocomplete',['com.htmlxprs.autocomplete.directives','com.htmlxprs.autocomplete.controllers']);

angular.module('com.htmlxprs.autocomplete.directives',[]).directive('autoComplete',['$http',function($http){
return {
    restrict:'AE',
    scope:{
        selectedTags:'=model'
    },
    templateUrl:'/views/autocomplete-template.html',
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

        scope.suggestions=[];
        scope.selectedTags=[];
        scope.selectedIndex=-1;

        scope.resetList = function(index) {
            scope.suggestions=[];
        }

        scope.removeTag=function(index){
            scope.selectedTags.splice(index,1);
        }

        scope.search=function(){
            $http.get(attrs.url+'?term='+scope.searchText).success(function(data){
                if(data.indexOf(scope.searchText)===-1){
                    data.unshift(scope.searchText);
                }
                scope.suggestions=data;
                scope.selectedIndex=-1;
            });
        }

        scope.addToSelectedTags=function(index){ 
            if(scope.selectedTags.indexOf(scope.suggestions[index])===-1){
                scope.selectedTags.push(scope.suggestions[index]);
                scope.searchText='';
                scope.suggestions=[];
            }
        }

        scope.checkKeyDown=function(event){
            if(event.keyCode===40){
                event.preventDefault();
                if(scope.selectedIndex+1 !== scope.suggestions.length){
                    scope.selectedIndex++;
                }
            }
            else if(event.keyCode===38){
                event.preventDefault();
                if(scope.selectedIndex-1 !== -1){
                    scope.selectedIndex--;
                }
            }
            else if(event.keyCode===13){
                scope.addToSelectedTags(scope.selectedIndex);
            }
        }

        scope.$watch('selectedIndex',function(val){
            if(val!==-1) {
                scope.searchText = scope.suggestions[scope.selectedIndex];
            }
        });
    }
}}]);
```

This works well however there is a small issue, if you start typing and get some results and decide to NOT select any of them but move on to another part of the screen then the **suggestion list does not get cleared**, they remain on the screen,

so I thought of implementing ng-blur on the input field however the problem with that is when users click on any of the suggestions to add the tag ng-blur gets fired and users can't add the tag.

Is there any way of clearing the suggested list (which is an array of items displayed in ul>li tags) is there an alternative to ng-blur so I know when users move out of the input area?

Thanks

Comment: tried `ng-blur="suggestions=[]"`?

Comment: unfortunately that clears the suggestion list before the selection is added so when users click on a tag to add to the list nothing gets added.

Answer (score 0):

For the suggestion list , you can maintain one scope variable $scope.checkHover. That means on ng-mouseover event you can make this variable as true and on ng-mouseleave event make this variable as false . So while blurring out from the input text box, if this variable is true that means he is on the suggestion list and don't clear the suggestion list and if it false ,clear the suggestion list.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are multiple solutions to this problem, but my preferred one is to use `ng-mousedown`, like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-mousedown="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Click me!</div>

<h1>{{count}}</h1>

<p>This example will increase the value of the variable "count" every time a mouse button is clicked on the DIV element.</p>

</body>
</html>
```